# Php code gets executed instead of displayed in textarea, how to solve?

Tags: php, forms, textarea

Normally when we use:

```
<textarea><?php echo 'ok'; ?></textarea>
```

We get `<?php echo 'ok'; ?>` displayed inside the textarea. But on my website I get the `ok` inside the textarea. So the php code gets executed instead the php code is being showed.

Anybody knows how this can happen? To be clear, I don't want it. I want the code to be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running a `.php` file on a PHP-enabled web server... Use the HTML entities for the text you want (specifically the `<` and `>`, though potentially more):

```html
<textarea>&lt;?php echo 'ok'; ?&gt;</textarea>
```

Or you can treat it as a string server-side and HTML-encode it with PHP:

```
<textarea><?php echo htmlentities("<?php echo 'ok'; ?>"); ?></textarea>
```

---

Alternatively, if you don't want to use PHP at all, then simply don't use it.  Serve an `.html` file and/or disable PHP on the server:

```html
<textarea><?php echo 'ok'; ?></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it's not gonna solve my issue. I want to achieve/restore the normal behavior.

Comment: @Kip: I honestly wasn't expecting the `<textarea>` to treat the `<` and the `>` as HTML entities, but that seems to work too.  I've updated the answer.  I would still *highly recommend* HTML-encoding any output.  *Especially* if that output is in any way user-editable.  Otherwise you could expose users to [security risks](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/).